# Ngx-datatable: t.slice is not a function at t.set [as rows]

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble with ngx-datatable and I don't know why. Locally it works fine but after I uploaded it to my test test server it started giving me this error and not renderin table data.

This is the error:

```
main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1 
ERROR TypeError: t.slice is not a function
    at t.set [as rows] (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
    at tv (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
    at main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1
    at main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1
    at kv (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
    at m_ (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
    at main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1
    at Object.updateDirectives (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
    at Object.p_ [as updateDirectives] (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
    at Ev (main.f7a34d8496a7f0ff9898.js:1)
```

From the error I'm guessing it has something to do with the `rows` part of ngx-datatable so here's the code:

```
<ngx-datatable class="material" *ngIf="allClients" [rows]="allClients?.content" [columnMode]="'force'" [rowHeight]="50" [scrollbarH]="true"
                 [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" (activate)='selectRow($event)' [externalPaging]="true" (page)='setPage($event)' [count]="allClients.totalElements"
                 [offset]="allClients.pageable?.pageNumber" [limit]="allClients.size" [messages]="{emptyMessage:'Andmed puuduvad.'}">
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="companyName" name="NIMI" width="80">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <button routerLink="/clients/{{row.id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm p-0">{{row.companyName}}</button>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="firmRegNo" name="REG NR" width="80">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row?.firmRegNo}}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="address" name="AADRESS">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row?.address}}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="clientContract.contractNo" name="LEPINGU NR" width="50">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row?.clientContract?.contractNo}}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="TASU" prop="clientContract.monthlyPay" width="50">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row?.clientContract?.monthlyPay | currency:'EUR' }}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="STAATUS" prop="status" width="100">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{row?.status | status}}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </ngx-datatable>
```

So rows is `allClients?.content` which is an array as it's supposed to be.

Below is an example server response that is used to render the table. Any ideas?

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "companyName": "Selver OÜ",
            "firmRegNo": 12312323,
            "address": "Lai 12, Tartu, Tartu",
            "clientName": "1231231",
            "phoneOne": 13371337,
            "phoneTwo": 13371337,
            "email": "heiko@bitweb.ee",
            "explanation": "1231231",
            "clientContract": {
                "id": 4,
                "contractNo": 123,
                "startDate": "2019-10-22T21:00:00.000+0000",
                "endDate": null,
                "monthlyPay": 1231,
                "clientContractFiles": [],
                "permanentContract": true,
                "archived": false
            },
            "status": "active",
            "objects": []
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "companyName": "Coop OÜ",
            "firmRegNo": 521123121,
            "address": "Lai 14, Tartu, Tartu",
            "clientName": "Mari Maasikas",
            "phoneOne": 58586161,
            "phoneTwo": 6809600,
            "email": "selver@hotmail.com",
            "explanation": "Testing123",
            "clientContract": null,
            "status": "temporarily_inactive",
            "objects": []
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "companyName": "Prisma OÜ",
            "firmRegNo": 374121126,
            "address": "Lai 13, Tartu, Tartu",
            "clientName": "Mari Maasikas",
            "phoneOne": 58586161,
            "phoneTwo": 6809600,
            "email": "selver@hotmail.com",
            "explanation": "Testing123",
            "clientContract": null,
            "status": "inactive",
            "objects": []
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalPages": 3,
    "totalElements": 25,
    "last": false,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0,
    "numberOfElements": 10,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false
    },
    "first": true
}
```

Comment: Please post your error properly

Comment: @SnehaPawar edited post.

Comment: Tried changing the rows part so it only contains the "content" part, but still same stuff :/